# Extjs: remove the pipe '|' from toolbar separator

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

In extjs, the is this component `toolbar.separator`( `xtype: tbseparator`) which allows you to put a *vertical* space between toolbar items.

It's just that it shows a pipe-like character or a line to denote that component. I want to remove it. I want there to be empty space. I've played around with the configs but can't figure out how. Can anyone help?

Comment: check [tbspacer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Spacer)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you don't really need to use a spacer. Just specify a component with a width of however wide you want the space to be:

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    width: 30
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put this in your custom css file:

```
.x-toolbar-separator-horizontal {
    border-style: none;
}
```